# HTML table td meaning

Tags: html, html-table, semantics

In HTML table, what does `td` stand for? I mean literally, what is it an acronym for? Table division? Table data?

Comment: Kind of weird how everyone calls `td` a table "cell", but it's really a table datum (data, plural).

Comment: To clarify: "datum" is singular, "data" is plural.

Comment: While it may be true that "datum" is the singular form, there are few use cases for it. This is because "data" is treated like an uncountable noun, similar to "water" or "money". We ask "how much do you have?" and describe that amount with units of measurement. (ml, ¥, GiB) Or maybe we don't specify an exact amount. (A glass of water. A lot of money. A piece of data.) If somebody starts talking to me about a datum, I want to know how much a datum is. Is it a bit? A letter? A word? At that point we're back to measurement. Stick with "data", as a mass noun, and keep it simple. Off-topic. Sorry.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

It stands for [Table Data](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Answer (score 58):

table data cell

quickest answer:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TD

(edit)
here is the html5 edition:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-td-element

Comment: It's too bad the w3's documentation is such an eye sore.

Comment: I found W3C to be esoteric at first, but once one adjusts to the format is (for me, at least) the quickest and most reliable reference.

Answer (score 15):

It means **table data** which is basically a **cell** or **column**.

Note also that `tr` stands for **table row**.

Answer (score 10):

***TD*** stand for **Table Data.**

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, table data. It doesn't make sense if you don't know about th, table header, since without it table cell would be a better one.

Answer (score -1):

The fifth paragraph in [this section of the HTML 4.01 specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TD) explicitly states:

> Table cells may either contain "header" information (see the TH element) or "data" (see the TD element).